# Button Template style when selected

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a mvvm design pattern set up to do commands and workspaces so that a button is pressed and the proper workspace displays. The buttons have a template binding to pull in the proper image for the template based on the command. I have added another field to the command for a SelectedTemplateResource for when the button is selected out of the array of buttons. The DataTemplate is pulled into the mainwindow to display the buttons.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CommandsTemplate">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding Path=Command}" Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" Template="{Utilities:BindableResource {Binding Path=TemplateResource}}">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Command}">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>

                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Want I want to do is set the value of the setter to the SelectedTemplateResource like so in the Template of the button called TemplateResource. These are all handled through the mainwindowviewmodel to set the appropriate template per button and it works well but I'm not sure how to finish the selected state.

Also, I'm not entirely sure if I should be setting the datatrigger binding to the command path.

Can anybody help me with figuring out how to set the selected state of a button using the design mentioned above?

Cheers.

**EDIT**
I get the use of the togglebutton trigger however the binding is not working. Heres some more information as for some reason I keep getting key is null error in my app.xaml.cs

The ToggleButton is a datatemplate in a file called MainWindowResources.xaml (**ResourceDictionary**).
The MainWindow.xaml file pulls in this data template.
I have a bindableresource class to help with the static resource for the resource file.

```
public class BindableResource : StaticResourceExtension
{
    #region Fields
    private static readonly DependencyProperty dummyProperty;
    #endregion


    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets and sets my binding.
    /// </summary>
    public Binding MyBinding { get; set; }
    #endregion


    #region Constructor
    /// <summary>
    /// Static contruction of the dummy dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    static BindableResource()
    {
        dummyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Dummy", typeof(string), typeof(DependencyObject), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public BindableResource()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor with binding to set.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="binding"></param>
    public BindableResource(Binding binding)
    {
        MyBinding = binding;
    }
    #endregion


    #region External Members
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the resource key to bind to the resource.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceProvider"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var target = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
        var targetObject = (FrameworkElement)target.TargetObject;

        MyBinding.Source = targetObject.DataContext;
        var DummyDO = new DependencyObject();
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(DummyDO, dummyProperty, MyBinding);

        ResourceKey = DummyDO.GetValue(dummyProperty);

        return base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

However this does not work for the triggers setter value.

```
<DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton Command="{Binding Path=Command}" Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" Template="{Utilities:BindableResource {Binding Path=TemplateResource}}">
                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{Utilities:BindableResource {Binding Path=SelectedTemplateResource}}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                </ToggleButton>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding out this really is not possible to do in pure xaml I brought out the c# and create a custom control... this is very basic and can be improved on and I will have change a bit of it but ultimately a custom control solves the issue so that you can hit the click event from within the resource dictionary and change the template on the fly.

```
public class TabButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTemplateProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedTemplate", typeof(ControlTemplate), typeof(TabButton));

    public ControlTemplate SelectedTemplate
    {
        get { return base.GetValue(SelectedTemplateProperty) as ControlTemplate; }
        set { base.SetValue(SelectedTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public TabButton()
    {
        this.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(TabButton_Click);
    }

    ~TabButton()
    {

    }

    public void TabButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ControlTemplate template = (ControlTemplate)this.FindResource("Environmental Template Selected");
        (sender as TabButton).Template = template;
    }
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I've understood what you want exactly. You want to change the button's template if it's selected yes?

Firstly a standard button doesn't have a the notion of being "selected". You want a `ToggleButton` for that. That way you can trigger on its `IsChecked` property to set your template.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CommandsTemplate">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton Command="{Binding Path=Command}" Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" Template="{Utilities:BindableResource {Binding Path=TemplateResource}}">
                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{Utilities:BindableResource {Binding DataContext.SelectedTemplateResource}}">
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                </ToggleButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for, toggle button does make more sense, however the template does not switch when clicking on the button.

Comment: Can you check your output for binding errors. I just took a guess at the binding path in the setter.

Comment: Keeps saying the key is null... nothing in the output console... the method looks correct, probably just a silly binding constraint.

Comment: Now that I think of it, the key is null as far as the value is concerned, I wonder if it has anything to do with my bindableresource class that handles the service. I should also note that this datatemplate is within a resource file.

Comment: I've edited my question with the binding issue... still no luck.

Comment: I see you've removed the DataContext bit from my binding. Was it wrong? Can you step through your ProvideValue function? Grab the return object from BindingOperations.SetBinding() and check its Status property.

Comment: The datacontext wasn't showing up in intellisense, that it didn't work with it so I assumed it was just a guess. However, I can't even get to the part where setbinding occurs... if i remove the style... i can get to it with the first resource binding however I came across something that says that the way this is setup won't work due to property precedence? What are your thoughts? I made a new post but it wasn't very helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112798/resource-1-works-2-doesnt

Comment: H.B. is correct in your other question. Didn't think of that, sorry! His work around should work ok though. I would try and step through your ProvideValue() and check that the binding is succeeding via the Status like I said.

Comment: It doesn't get into ProvideValue for the second resource, which is the error saying key is null.

Comment: To clarify it gets to the constructor, sets the binding to mybinding, and then throws up after leaving the constructor.

Comment: Sorry, never used markup extensions yet. Can you add another setter to display the binding somewhere, so at least you know that it is what you are expecting. eg change the button content to it: <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding SelectedTemplateResource}">

Comment: It is what I"m expecting, when I put the breakpoint in the constructor and look through its properties, it pulls in the appropriate resource I want. Setting the property to content removes the error however the effect doesn't work... clicking the togglebutton does not change the style.