# Resource 1 works, 2 doesn't

Tags: wpf

```
<ToggleButton Command="{Binding Path=Command}" Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" Template="{Utilities:BindableResource {Binding Path=TemplateResource}}">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{Utilities:BindableResource {Binding Path=SelectedTemplateResource}}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

The first bindable resource works for "TemplateResource" on the template property of togglebutton however "SelectedTemplateResource" does not work within the tiggers setter. This code is within a resourcedictionary where the actual resource is within a themed resourcedictionary.

I get an error saying key is null for xamlparseexception for the setter value. I've been stairing at this for hours but cannot figure out why it doesn't work... If I take out the style and replace the first binding with the second resource it does display proper however the binding within the style will not work.

Does anybody have any idea why?

**EDIT**
I just tried this but no luck.

```
                <ToggleButton Command="{Binding Path=Command}" Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}">
                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{Utilities:BindableResource {Binding Path=TemplateResource}}" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{Utilities:BindableResource {Binding Path=SelectedTemplateResource}}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: You'll want to look at [dependency property value precendence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) as this would not work even without the error.

Comment: Is there anyway around this? I have a mvvm pattern set up around commands and workspaces and the command is essentially a button with a specified themed resource... which does work... its just getting the affect of a selected state resource to update when the button is clicked.

Comment: To fix the precedence override you just need to move the local value (`Template="..."`) to a `Setter` in the style.

Comment: I just edited my question, I think I'm confused by "local" value.

Comment: Local value. A local value might be set through the convenience of the "wrapper" property, which also equates to setting as an attribute or property element in XAML, or by a call to the SetValue API using a property of a specific instance. If you set a local value by using a binding or a resource, these each act in the precedence as if a direct value was set.

**Is this not what I did in my edit?**

Comment: You added another Trigger-Setter, this will fix the precedence issue, but you could just add a Setter in the Style directly without triggers, this is then the default which can be overriden by the trigger. Anyway, as i said, you will only run into this issue after fixing your main resource problem, so of course this "does not work".

Comment: If it won't work then why suggest it? It was suggested to me from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108620/button-template-style-when-selected/10108948#comment12957739_10108948 to create the style.

Comment: I think you don't understand the problem, if your resource-lookup does not work your style will be useless, all i am saying is that **if you get your resources to work** your original code would not do anything because the local value would override the trigger. So if you fix that now you still end up with something that "does not work" because of your resource problem.

Comment: Is it not possible to point to a resource in a trigger from another resourcedictionary? The resource lookup does work outside of the style.

Comment: **I don't know**, if i did i would have posted an *answer*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding out this really is not possible to do in pure xaml I brought out the c# and create a custom control... this is very basic and can be improved on and I will have change a bit of it but ultimately a custom control solves the issue so that you can hit the click event from within the resource dictionary and change the template on the fly.

```
public class TabButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTemplateProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedTemplate", typeof(ControlTemplate), typeof(TabButton));

    public ControlTemplate SelectedTemplate
    {
        get { return base.GetValue(SelectedTemplateProperty) as ControlTemplate; }
        set { base.SetValue(SelectedTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public TabButton()
    {
        this.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(TabButton_Click);
    }

    ~TabButton()
    {

    }

    public void TabButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ControlTemplate template = (ControlTemplate)this.FindResource("Environmental Template Selected");
        (sender as TabButton).Template = template;
    }
}
```

Cheers.